# Can a self signed TLS/DTLS digital certificate be forged?

Tags: tls, man-in-the-middle

I have quite minimal understanding in cryptography. I was very much hoping to understand whether a self signed certificate's fingerprint be copied/reverse engineered on another certificate. Many VoIP platforms use certificate fingerprints as a form of authentication. Essentially, can a certificate be reverse engineered to contain the same fingerprint as the target certificate?
I am not referring to collisions since these are impossible, rather editing the actual code of a self signed certificate.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not refering to collisions since these are impossible

You are asking for something even harder - a [preimage attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack). Preimage attack means to create an input for a hash resulting in a predefined output. Collision has the weaker requirement of creating two inputs for the hash which result in the same (not predefined) output.

A certificate fingerprint is a cryptographic hash over the certificate, so having the same fingerprint either means to have the same certificate or to have created a different certificate with the same fingerprint - which would be a preimage attack. Even with a weak hash algorithms like MD5 (were collisions are doable) this is considered currently practically impossible.

Or alternatively you would need to be able to use exactly the same certificate. Copying the certificate itself is easy - it is usually public and with TLS one could just query the server and it will send it. But to actually use the certificate yourself as a server certificate or for signing, you need to have the private key which matches the public key contained in the certificate. But re-creating the private key from the public key in the certificate is itself basically impossible. If you would be able to do this, then you would have broken a corner stone of modern cryptography.

Answer (score 0):

The fingerprint of a certificate is a hash value, computed over all the certificate data + signature.

Discrete certificates having the same fingerprint is **by definition**, a collision for the hash function used to compute the fingerprint. You can edit the code or do whatever you want to build the certificate in question, but at the end of the day what this amounts to is trying to find a collision for the target fingerprint.

Not impossible (especially in the case of weaker hash functions), but generally accepted to be computationally infeasible for the widely used hash functions today.